# insert a post with category and tags using laravel corcel?

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, categories, corcel

I am using Corcel^5.0.0 with Laravel 8 to creating a post in wordpress. i m trying insert a new post with category id and tags.

post is working fine but when insert a category get error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::associate()

```
        $post = new Post;
        $post->post_title = $title;
        $post->post_content = $content;
        $post->post_status = $post_status;
        $post->taxonomies('categories')->associate($cat_id);
        $post->save();
```

I also have this in my controller and the Post model class:

```
use Corcel\Post as Corcel;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the belongsToMany methods

```
->attach($cat_id) instead of ->associate which is for a belongsTo relationship

->sync($cat_ids_array)

->detach($cat_id)
```

Comment: these method are not working